# Does an algorithm exist that takes an image of the night sky and tell you where in the milky way that perspective likely originates?

Tags: fundamental-astronomy, observational-astronomy, positional-astronomy, algorithm

In Stargate they talk about using the stars on other planets to figure out their location. I know that's fiction, but it made me wonder if such an algorithm (with arguably little usefulness right now) exists.